# Javascript Update URL With Options From Multiple Form Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, url

I have a form with 2 sets of checkboxes with a view this could be 3 or 4 down the line.

For this question I have 2 which each have >5 checkboxes and multiple items can be selected in those check boxes.

When a user selects the checkboxes I want to update the URL and refresh with parameters which I'll be using to filter content.

URL I want:

example.com/category/?content=video_static&channel=facebook-ads_instagram-ads

URL I'm getting:

example.com/category/?content=video&content=static&channel=facebook-ads&channel=instagram-ads

I'm not currently changing the URL with javascript but just a form input and submit. I'm thinking I'll need to use Javascript to enable better URL handling.

I want to use undercores to then seperate the checkbox selections which at the minute I'm happy to just refresh the page.

I appreciate this may be very simple for some but Javascript isn't my thing and I have about 20 tabs open trying. Any help is appreciated.

Here is example form (please ignore the tweo different checkbox HTML formats, I hadn't updated the second before this):

```html
   <form id="abFilter" method="get" role="form" action="">
        <div class="list-group">
        <h3>Content Type</h3>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="static" name="content" value="static">
            <label for="static">static</label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="carousel" name="content" value="carousel">
            <label for="carousel">carousel</label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="video" name="content" value="video">
            <label for="video">video</label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="gif" name="content" value="gif">
            <label for="gif">gif</label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="dpa" name="content" value="dpa">
            <label for="dpa">dpa</label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="stories" name="content" value="stories">
            <label for="stories">stories</label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="" id="influencer" name="content" value="influencer">
            <label for="influencer">influencer</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group">
        <h3>Channels</h3>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="facebook-ads">
            facebook-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="instagram-ads">
            instagram-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="google-ads">
            google-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="microsoft-ads">
            microsoft-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="tiktok-ads">
            tiktok-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="snapchat-ads">
            snapchat-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="youtube-ads">
            youtube-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="pinterest-ads">
            pinterest-ads
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="podcast-ads">
            podcast-ads
            </label>
            </div>
        </div> 
    <button id="select">Apply Filter</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it:

```js
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit=ev=>{
  ev.preventDefault();
  let o={};
  ev.target.querySelectorAll("[name]:checked").forEach(el=>{
   (o[el.name]=o[el.name]||[]).push(el.value)})
  console.log(location.pathname+"?"+
   Object.entries(o).map(([v,f])=>
   v+"="+f.join("_")).join("&")
  );
}
```

```html
<form id="abFilter" method="get" role="form" action="">
<div class="list-group">
<h3>Content Type</h3>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="static" name="content" value="static">
    <label for="static">static</label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="carousel" name="content" value="carousel">
    <label for="carousel">carousel</label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="video" name="content" value="video">
    <label for="video">video</label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="gif" name="content" value="gif">
    <label for="gif">gif</label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="dpa" name="content" value="dpa">
    <label for="dpa">dpa</label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="stories" name="content" value="stories">
    <label for="stories">stories</label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="influencer" name="content" value="influencer">
    <label for="influencer">influencer</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
<h3>Channels</h3>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="facebook-ads">
    facebook-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="instagram-ads">
    instagram-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="google-ads">
    google-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="microsoft-ads">
    microsoft-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="tiktok-ads">
    tiktok-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="snapchat-ads">
    snapchat-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="youtube-ads">
    youtube-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="pinterest-ads">
    pinterest-ads
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="channel" value="podcast-ads">
    podcast-ads
    </label>
    </div>
</div> 
<button id="select">Apply Filter</button>
</form>
```

Instead of only showing the new location string with `console.log()` you should of course use it to apply your filter settings, either through an AJAX call or simply by replacing the current `document.location.href`.